# How does Maven help in documenting the provenance for Maven jars?

Tags: maven, package

How does a Java package published on Maven documents the provenance (origin and license) of an open source project packaged and published in such a public repo?

In particular what can I do to document and how should I document my code when I am the author and publisher of a package?

And what if this is a package (possibly modified) that I have not authored but that I only publish as Maven Central Jar?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking which Pom elements to add?

Comment: For instance I guess.

Comment: @RubberDuck yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can simple add this information to your POM file. The following is an [example from the Maven POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#More_Project_Information).

> ```
> <licenses>
>   <license>
>     <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
>     <url>https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
>     <distribution>repo</distribution>
>     <comments>A business-friendly OSS license</comments>
>   </license>
> </licenses>
>
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
>                       https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>   ...
>   <organization>
>     <name>Codehaus Mojo</name>
>     <url>http://mojo.codehaus.org</url>
>   </organization>
> </project>
> ```

As for your last question, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but I would say point the URL to your fork.

Comment: Thanks. You mean point the url to your fork? which url? the license URL?

Comment: The project URL @PhilippeOmbredanne

Comment: If I can put more than one license <tags>, would  this mean  that all the licenses apply or that this is a choice of licenses?

Comment: I assume that would mean you're dual licensing @PhilippeOmbredanne, but that is just an assumption.